# Gitlab Webhook and Jenkins: No Data Received

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have been following the below links in order to integrate Gitlab with Jenkins using web hooks. All the below links mention to receive 'JSON' or 'payload' or token over at Jenkins side, but I do not see anything when I try to echo or print these parameters in the Shell script of Jenkins configurations.

In shell script I have this, but I never receive any payloads:

> echo "the build worked! The payload is $payload"

I do see some JSON coming through on /var/log/Jenkins/Jenkins.logs, but I want to see the messages coming in inside my 'Console Output', so that I can use the messages coming in from Gitlab to whether trigger a build or not.

Most of these links mention options are not available via Gitlab. One article was mentioning to convert web hook format to application/json, but there are no such options on the Gitlab UI.
[How to process a github webhook payload in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407332/how-to-process-a-github-webhook-payload-in-jenkins)
http://chloky.com/github-json-payload-in-jenkins/

Jenkins Settings:
[image: Jenkins Settings]

Gitlab webhook:

> http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/job/Interim_Build/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try two solutions (both working for me):

1. convert json data from Gitlab webhook using this elegant proxy written in Go https://github.com/akira/githookproxy .
   It will take the webhook request, and translate it to a request to the `target_url` in the format of:

   - `payload`: JSON body
   - `START`: Start commit hash
   - `END`: End commit hash
   - `REFNAME`: Ref name
2. emulate jenkins as a Gitlab CI using this Jenkins plugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin

For me the best is the first because it is simple and more transparent.

Comment: Thank you for providing "*githookproxy*" plugin. I installed it and got pretty close, but when running **./proxy -listen <listen address>:port** I am not sure what ***port*** I should be listening to.
Please advice, as I am getting pretty close in making this work - hopefully.

Comment: @DevGirl I am glad the answer work for you. You are free to choose which port you want (e.g 7060) but be sure to setup gitlab correctly following the readme of the project. Do you run proxy on the same machine of gitlab?

Comment: I am not sure about how to check the proxies? Is that important?

Comment: How do I check for proxy? So, I can just use any port?

Comment: @DevGirl, if you are unsure try with 7060, if it is busy the proxy will halt. If that is the case try with another one. If you are using linux you can use the command described here to get a list of busy ports http://superuser.com/a/529844 . Let me know if you solve your issue.

Comment: Any idea how can i get the variable name which contains JSON result sent from GitLab when any project is created? The plugin above is for webhook as asked by OP. I am looking for _system hook_ where i can run a Jenkins job by fetching JSON data sent from GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

GitLab and GitHub are two separate products. So, the documentation or [links](http://chloky.com/github-json-payload-in-jenkins/) for GitHub webhooks that you are referring will not apply to GitLab webhooks.

GitLab invokes the webhook URL with a JSON payload in the request body that carries a lot of information about the GitLab event that led to the webhook invocation. For example, the [GitLab webhook push event payload](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#push-events) carries the following information in it:

```
{
  "object_kind": "push",
  "before": "95790bf891e76fee5e1747ab589903a6a1f80f22",
  "after": "da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
  "checkout_sha": "da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
  "user_id": 4,
  "user_name": "John Smith",
  "user_username": "jsmith",
  "user_email": "john@example.com",
  "user_avatar": "https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/d4c74594d841139328695756648b6bd6?s=8://s.gravatar.com/avatar/d4c74594d841139328695756648b6bd6?s=80",
  "project_id": 15,
  "project":{
    "id": 15,
    "name":"Diaspora",
    "description":"",
    "web_url":"http://example.com/mike/diaspora",
    "avatar_url":null,
    "git_ssh_url":"git@example.com:mike/diaspora.git",
    "git_http_url":"http://example.com/mike/diaspora.git",
    "namespace":"Mike",
    "visibility_level":0,
    "path_with_namespace":"mike/diaspora",
    "default_branch":"master",
    "homepage":"http://example.com/mike/diaspora",
    "url":"git@example.com:mike/diaspora.git",
    "ssh_url":"git@example.com:mike/diaspora.git",
    "http_url":"http://example.com/mike/diaspora.git"
  },
  "repository":{
    "name": "Diaspora",
    "url": "git@example.com:mike/diaspora.git",
    "description": "",
    "homepage": "http://example.com/mike/diaspora",
    "git_http_url":"http://example.com/mike/diaspora.git",
    "git_ssh_url":"git@example.com:mike/diaspora.git",
    "visibility_level":0
  },
  "commits": [
    {
      "id": "b6568db1bc1dcd7f8b4d5a946b0b91f9dacd7327",
      "message": "Update Catalan translation to e38cb41.",
      "timestamp": "2011-12-12T14:27:31+02:00",
      "url": "http://example.com/mike/diaspora/commit/b6568db1bc1dcd7f8b4d5a946b0b91f9dacd7327",
      "author": {
        "name": "Jordi Mallach",
        "email": "jordi@softcatala.org"
      },
      "added": ["CHANGELOG"],
      "modified": ["app/controller/application.rb"],
      "removed": []
    },
    {
      "id": "da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
      "message": "fixed readme",
      "timestamp": "2012-01-03T23:36:29+02:00",
      "url": "http://example.com/mike/diaspora/commit/da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
      "author": {
        "name": "GitLab dev user",
        "email": "gitlabdev@dv6700.(none)"
      },
      "added": ["CHANGELOG"],
      "modified": ["app/controller/application.rb"],
      "removed": []
    }
  ],
  "total_commits_count": 4
}
```

The [Jenkins GitLab plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin) makes this webhook payload information available in the [Jenkins Global Variable](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference) **env**. The [available **env** variables](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#defined-variables) are as follows:

```
gitlabBranch
gitlabSourceBranch
gitlabActionType
gitlabUserName
gitlabUserEmail
gitlabSourceRepoHomepage
gitlabSourceRepoName
gitlabSourceNamespace
gitlabSourceRepoURL
gitlabSourceRepoSshUrl
gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl
gitlabMergeRequestTitle
gitlabMergeRequestDescription
gitlabMergeRequestId
gitlabMergeRequestIid
gitlabMergeRequestState
gitlabMergedByUser
gitlabMergeRequestAssignee
gitlabMergeRequestLastCommit
gitlabMergeRequestTargetProjectId
gitlabTargetBranch
gitlabTargetRepoName
gitlabTargetNamespace
gitlabTargetRepoSshUrl
gitlabTargetRepoHttpUrl
gitlabBefore
gitlabAfter
gitlabTriggerPhrase
```

Just as you would read Jenkins job parameters from [Jenkins Global Variable](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference) **params** in your job pipeline script, you could read webhook payload fields from [Jenkins Global Variable](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference) **env**:

```
echo "My Jenkins job parameter is ${params.MY_PARAM_NAME}"
echo "One of Jenkins job webhook payload field is ${env.gitlabMergedByUser}"
```

Hope, the above information helps solve your problem.

Comment: is it possible to access individual commits ?