# How to name the custom workspace in Jenkins job with branch name triggered by Github webhook?

Tags: github, jenkins, devops

I have created a single job in Jenkins to be triggered by commit on any branches in the GitHub using Webhook.
I want to create a custom workspace for each job trigger with respective to the branch commit.

I Tried following options and could not achieve it. Appreciate for any help.

```
Job Name : Test_Clone
```

Used advance options in general section and tried below options to name the workspace dynamically.

1. `Test_Clone_${GIT_BRANCH}` - always gives the branch name from previous build.
2. `Test_Clone_${ref}` - tried to use ref as defined in GitHub webhook payload, with no result.

To achieve: Ex: Commit from GitHub branch `release-2.13.0`, Jenkins should create workspace with name `Test_Clone_release-2.13.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try and setup

- first a payload variable in your Jenkins build, as described in "[How to process a github webhook payload in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31572888/6309)"
- then a webhook url (on GitHub side) of:

  ```
  http://<<yourserver>>/job/<<yourjob>>/buildWithParameters?token=<<yourtoken>>
  ```

Then your Jenkins job would have the xml webhook payload in it, which you can analyze ([with `jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)) and extract the ['`ref`' which includes the branch name](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent).

From there, I would call (chain) a second job with a "`branch`" parameter  (unless you can write a [pipeline DSL](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/) with Jenkins 2) with that branch name, in order for the second job to use a custom workspace name based on that parameter

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this option but in different way, created a first job to define env variable with GIT_BRANCH and use the same in next job and it works. But trying to achieve the same without creating a seperate job just to define env variable or parsing json, if their is no other way, then I will live with one job just to prepare env variable. if this info helps: I have a build pipeline with 4 jobs defined as upstream and downstream projects and

Comment: That is where pipeline DSL can help, to chain multiple steps into one job

Comment: We are not using pipeline DSL to chain multiple steps, since we have smaller project pipeline we are using upstream/downstream model by defining trigger paramterized build in post build action.