# How to use Generic webhook trigger plugin in jenkins?

Tags: github, jenkins

Trying to parse the Github webhook payload(specifically need tag_name from release) in jenkins and make the values available in the build job.
Tried using Generic Webhook Trigger plugin as mentioned in the link below
[How to process a github webhook payload in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407332/how-to-process-a-github-webhook-payload-in-jenkins)
but without success. Can someone provide an example how to use this plugin and get the tag_name value in Jenkins job ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this post should help https://bjurr.com/continuous-integration-with-gitlab-and-jenkins/

In short, you will need to create a webhook in GH and a Jenkins Pipeline. Here is an example https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/blob/master/sandbox/multibranch.jenkinsfile

or using Jenkins Job DSL. (See github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin)

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

You may add a variable named `ref` and expression `$.ref`

Then you can have a filter with text `$ref` and regexp `^(refs/tags/.+)$`

Now the job will only trigger when a tag is pushed.

There is a test case on this in the repo: https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd/github/github-push-tag.feature