# Unable to filter the github webhook trigger in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have followed the link given below to trigger my jenkins **pipeline** job only when a push occurs on master branch.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin

Configuration in github:
[image: Github Webhook configuration]

To filter according to the payload 'ref' tag, optional filter is set in jenkins pipeline job.
[image: Assigning ref value to 'ref' variable]

Then i applied optional filter on 'ref' variable, to allow only **master** branch
[image: Filter 'ref' variable]

Finally a token filter is added, that is unique to my repository
[image: Token filter]

Token filter works as expected, but the filter on ref variable is not having any impact on the pipeline job. Job will be triggered irrespective of what value is given on the regular expression.

Eg. Job is getting triggered even if I delete a tag!
[image: 'ref' tag when a tag was deleted]

I am not able to understand this behavior, neither I think that I am missing something in the configuration. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a token, that might explain why the job is *always* triggered:

> ### Trigger only specific job

> When using the plugin in several jobs, you will have the same URL trigger all jobs. If you want to trigger only a certain job you can:

> - Use the token-parameter and have different tokens for different jobs. Using only the token means only jobs with that exact token will be visible for that request. This will increase performance and reduce responses of each invocation.

- **Or**, add some request parameter (or header, or post content) and use the regexp filter to trigger only if that parameter has a specific value.

In your case, try and use only the `un:pw` (username/password) in your URL, without a token, to see of your Optional Filter applies.

Comment: if you look at 'Authentication' section of 'https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin', it talks about using both webhook trigger and token.

Comment: @Renjith try using only un:pw *or* token, to test if the filter applies

Comment: I tied https://un:pw@jenkins.myOrg.com/job/myJob/build. Unchecked the 'Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)'. It triggered the job. but the filter dint worked.i.e. it is not filtering and it allows all the 'ref' data to trigger the job. And the url 'https://un:pw@jenkins.myorg.com/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke' (which is supped to be the web hook url) is receiving request, but  the filter is not allowing it to pass through.

Comment: @Renjith Maybe this is a known issue? (https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/issues/38) What version of that plugin are you using?

Comment: I am not sure about the version as I dont have admin access in jenkins. But I am trying a workaround (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407332/how-to-process-a-github-webhook-payload-in-jenkins) where I could access the web hook 'payload' inside my groovy script and validate the ref tag. It looks good.. But the other one was a much cleaner approach!