# Use the tag in GitLab webhook in jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, webhooks

I have a webhook in GitLab to trigger a Jenkins job when ever a new tag is created. Is there a way to use the new tag that triggered the Jenkins job in the Jenkins job? For example, lets say I pushed the tag `v.1.5` to my repo.

```
git tag -a v1.5 -m "version 1.5"
git push --tags
```

Now, I want to use the tag `v.1.5` in the shell execution in the Jenkins build (Execute shell).

```
echo <tag that triggered this job>
```

[image: Jenkins build]

Is there a way to read and use the tag from the POST request?

Comment: GitLab webhook sends payload with information. It is possible for Jenkins to access this payload explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407332/how-to-process-a-github-webhook-payload-in-jenkins and here you can see payload for Tag Event webhook: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#tag-events and this field might have your tag in it: "ref": "refs/tags/v1.0.0",

Answer (score 0):

You can read the tag from the local repo using `git describe`.

```sh
tag=$(git describe --tags)
echo "tag = "$tag
```